# Сan't uninstall the WPS Office v. 11.1.0.9080 on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wps-office

There's no way I can remove the WPS Office...
I installed WPS Office 2019 For Linux v. 11.1.0.9080 from **wps-office_11.1.0.9080.XA_amd64.deb** using GDebi.
Now I need to remove it.
In Ubuntu 19.10 I use command:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge wps-office
```

I have got result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  wps-office*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1,140 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 308773 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing wps-office (11.1.0.9080.XA) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 1252, in __getitem__
    return self._parser.get(self._name, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 799, in get
    d)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 394, in before_get
    self._interpolate_some(parser, option, L, value, section, defaults, 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 444, in _interpolate_some
    "found: %r" % (rest,))
configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found: '%U_1918052320.desktop;org.gnome.Evince.desktop;'
dpkg: error processing package wps-office (--remove):
 installed wps-office package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wps-office
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Did you changed Python in your system? Please also add output of `sudo find / -name "*1918052320.desktop"` to determine the location of the *%U_1918052320.desktop* file from the error message.

Comment: I'm newbie to Linux and Ubuntu. I hope I haven't changed. But I recently installed the  python with an anaconda distribution. As far as I can understand, an anaconda puts the python in a completely different place than system (Ubuntu's) python3. The output of you command: 

`find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/home/vgrinkov/.local/share/applications/dc_evince %U_1918052320.desktop
`

Comment: I would recommend to move the problematic desktop file out the way with `mv /home/vgrinkov/.local/share/applications/dc_evince %U_1918052320.desktop ~/wrong.desktop` and then resume uninstallation.

Comment: got the same result (same lines) `... configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found: '%U_1918052320.desktop;org.gnome.Evince.desktop;'
dpkg: error processing package wps-office (--purge):
 installed wps-office package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wps-office`

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem on fresh Ubuntu 19.10 VM, but if `apt-get` fails - you can try low-level command:

```
sudo dpkg --purge wps-office
```

(see `man dpkg` for details locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/dpkg.1.html))

Comment: N0rbert, thank you for the advice. The command: 
`sudo dpkg --purge wps-office`
produced the same output...